# Mac PyCharm 2018.2: Keyboard shortcut to toggle regex from the search bar?

Tags: macos, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

As of PyCharm 2018.1, I was able to hit Cmd+F then Option+G to open the search bar with Regex enabled, but after installing 2018.2 Option+G inserts a © sign. I tried hovering over the Regex option, but no tooltip appears. I cannot find anything in Jetbrains' documentation. How do I toggle the Regex option directly from the input bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use `Cmd + F` and then `Option + x` to enable/toggle Regex in the Find toolbar.